# AIN SIP Java API to register to a asterisk server?

Tags: java, sip, asterisk

is there any tutorials or docs that explains how to register to a asterisk server using Jain SIP api in a java application?

i have already written a piece of java code that allows my java client to directly interact and send and receive messages to another client directly via p2p but i was wondering if i can enhance this app to instead register to a Asterisk server and send messages to that server which will then get relayed to the appropriate client.

Possible? Or do i need a different API to connect and register to an asterisk server?

Answer (score 1):

Two parts:

Part A: Yes, you can register using JAIN-SIP. [The java doc shows](https://developer.opencloud.com/devportal/devportal/apis/jainsip/1.1/docs/javax/sip/message/Request.html#REGISTER) that there is a `REGISTER` method as part of the `Request` class.

One example of the usage is ([from this learning resource](http://alex.bikfalvi.com/teaching/upf/2013/architecture_and_signaling/lab/sip/)):

```
Request request = this.messageFactory.createRequest(
    requestURI,
    "REGISTER",
    callIdHeader,
    cSeqHeader,
    fromHeader,
    toHeader,
    viaHeaders,
    maxForwardsHeader);
```

Part B: I'm not sure of the use cases for your client, but... If you're not going to have a dynamic IP for your client -- you don't actually need to register the client with Asterisk. In your `/etc/asterisk/sip.conf` set `host=10.0.0.8` or `host=jain.example.com` as opposed to `host=dynamic`

Comment: where can i specify the clients username and password?